# Why navigationMixin.Navigate is not working on aura:application

Tags: lightning-web-components

JS

```
filePreview(event) {
    // Naviagation Service to the show preview
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__namedPage',
        attributes: {
            pageName: 'filePreview'
        },
        state: {
            // assigning ContentDocumentId to show the preview of file
            selectedRecordId: event.currentTarget.dataset.id
        }
    })
}
```

When i opening this component aura:component it is working fine but if this component is redirected to aura:application and then opening this function with on click then it is no doing anything